# Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory' has already been defined

Tags: magento2, module, setup-upgrade, magento-core

I'm getting this error after I ran the `setup:upgrade` command and this was after the upgrade to Magento 2.1.3

> Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory' from '/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory' has been already defined in '/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory'.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you clear the var directories `rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache` and also do you have a duplicate copy of Magento_CatalogInventory module in your app/code directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cloned your Magento from Github, so all your core is in folder `app/code/Magento/`, you need remove it and run the composer command to have your core in the folder `vendor/`.

> Note that you **shouldn't clone** the repository, next time install using **Composer**.

These are the steps that I used to fix:

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/di/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ app/code/Magento/ vendor/magento composer.lock

chmod 777 -R *

composer update -vvvv

php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {}

find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {}

chmod u+x bin/magento

bin/magento maintenance:disable

bin/magento cache:clean
```

The **Composer** command will install de vendor modules.

Comment: This works as you deleted the contents of app/code/ using app/code/*. If you happen to have any other extension you installed manually these will be lost in this deletion. You need only delete "/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventor/". The likely hood is you have installed CatalogInventor inventory using composer and so you have the same extension twice (or maybe different versions).

Comment: Followed the steps and it worked. Just upgraded to 2.2 from 2.1.9. :D Thanks!

Comment: So far `rm -rf vendor/composer` is the only thing that does the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you installed Magento by cloning the github repository and then tried to upgrade using composer. The problem is that composer places the core modules in the `Vendor` directory while cloning the repository results in them being in `App/Code` directory, so now you have duplicates. You should remove the `App/Code/Magento` directory to solve the error. Note that you shouldn't clone the repository, next time install with composer.