# Magento 2.1.9 to Magento 2.2.1 upgrade error

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

I am trying to update to latest version but when I run upgrade command from the console than its showing below upgrade error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps, and then try

```
rm -rf app/code/Magento/ var/* vendor/*
chmod 777 -R *
composer update && composer install
php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {}
find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {}
chmod u+x bin/magento
bin/magento maintenance:disable
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Refer this for more info : [Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory' has already been defined](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152968/module-magento-cataloginventory-has-already-been-defined)

Comment: Hi, I have already tried that but now working.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from **Magento 2.1.9** to **Magento 2.2.1** using these commands

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115459/48571)